# SvelteKit, SCSS and Vite: Error: Undefined variable, Error: Undefined variable

Tags: sass, svelte, vite, sveltekit

After setting up a new SvelteKit project, adding the vitePreprocess preprocessor to svelte.config.js and adding the SCSS variable file path to preprocessorOptions in vite.config.js. This works and I can use variables in my components, however whenever I do I am presented with the following error:

```
Error in referenced file

Error: Undefined variable.
  ╷
3 │     color: $red; 
  │            ^^^^
  ╵
app/src/routes/+page.svelte.vite-preprocess.scss 3:12  root stylesheetsvelte(style)
```

**svelte.config.js**

```
import path from 'path'
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-auto';
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';

const config = {
  kit: {
    adapter: adapter(),
  },
  preprocess: [vitePreprocess()]
};
 
export default config
```

**vite.config.js**

```
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [sveltekit()],
    css: {
        preprocessorOptions: {
            scss: {                                 
                additionalData: `
                    @use 'src/scss/variables' as *;    
                    @use 'src/scss/mixins' as *;
                `,
            },
        }
    }
})
```

How can I fix or remove this error?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `svelte-preprocess`

```
import preprocess from "svelte-preprocess"

const config = {
    
    preprocess: preprocess(({
        scss:{
            prependData:'use "../styles/functions"'
        }
    })),

    kit: {
        
        adapter: adapter()
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've updated the vite.config.js file to use import instead of use as shown above, but unfortunately I'm still getting the same error flagged by Visual Studio Code. It's strange, as I can actually use the variable successfully in components.

Comment: Is your path to variables.scss correct?

Comment: It is correct, as I can use the variable $red from variables.scss in +page.svelte and it works, it just presents an error which I want to get rid of.

Comment: use `npm i -D svelte-preprocess `